# Count number of cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a case in Excel.

I want to find out, for example, how many hotelrooms that are rented on a specific date.

I have all the reservations in one sheet, with dates and number of days rented. 
An example:

A reservation with date start 10.01.2013 and rented for 4 days.
A reservation with date start 13.01.2013 and rented for 2 days
A reservation with date start 12.01.2013 and rented for 3 days.

The answer is that on the date 14.01.2013 there are three rooms that are rented out. But how can I get this number in Excel? What formula do I need to use?

Hope you have some great answers!

Comment: what have you tried to solve your problem? Here, on Stack Overflow you need to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. This is not a site where people have too much free time and do your homeworks for you. We're here to help you with your CODE that you can't get to work.

Comment: Well. I have tried CountIf function combined with FREQ.
=COUNIF(D:D;"<=41288")
I got an error message saying that the formula was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose A1:A3 are the dates, B1:B3 are the number of days rented, C1 is the specific date

You can try this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A3+B1:B3)>=C1)*1)`